# linking a new windows form with an existing project in c#

Tags: c#

I have a c# problem. I have created a project called 'classproject' and I have added several forms to project successfully and successfully ran the program, but there is this other windows form that I just added and when I double-clicked on the form, it took me to the code view and brought out this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class demo : Form
    {
        public demo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void demo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

    }

}
```

Now, my challenge is that the name of the project is meant to show by default after the namespace as in "namespace classproject" instead of "namespace WindowsFormsApplication1". Please can anyone help me out, what am I meant to do because have tried everything possible. Even if I change the name myself its still going to flag error... someone please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Is your designer class in the same namespace?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what your issue is. If you change the namespace manually in the code to `classproject` it should be fine. What error are you talking about? You would also need to change the designer code file as well (probably called `demo.Designer.cs`).

Just a side note as well. Standard naming convention for C# is to use Pascal-case (as in ClassProject).

Comment: Well it is a partial answer, partial comment I guess. I put what I thought would fix the issue, but I'm also looking for more clarification. Meh.

Comment: Well we ARE dealing with partial classes after all.

Answer (score 1):

You must change namespace in ALL files that was generated by Visual Studio. You can do it manually, or just set cursor on "WindowsFormsApplication1", press F2 and enter new name.

Optionaly you can also change namespace in project properties on Application tab - then all new files added to project will also have namespace that you set there.

Comment: Or use ReSharper...though I'm guessing he doesn't have it. +1 for the better alternative ways to fix the issue.